# XWIKI - Changing Parents of Page (does not get updated on nav)

Tags: xwiki

I would like to know why after I edit the parent of an existing page (e.g. "Sushi" page, under "Food" space; I open that page, open edit, and change the parent from WIKI > Food > Sushi, to WIKI > Japan > Sushi), it won't change its position on the sidebar (i.e. the "Sushi" page is still under the "Food" section in the sidebar, and in the food.webhome page rather than japan.webhome page.

Can someone tell me how to refresh it or something?

Thanks.

ingSiang

Answer (score 0):

(Note: Answer only applies to XWiki prior to version 7.2. Since version 7.2 the confusion should no longer appear.)

### What is going on here?

The problem is caused by a confusion between two concepts, the one being the parent-child relation between pages spanning up a tree, and the other one grouping pages into spaces. In XWiki, these concepts are not related, i.e. pages do not have to be in the same space to form parent-child relationships.

The membership of pages in a given space is often noted by the `<space>.<page>` notation; for example `Main.WebHome` is the page with name `WebHome` in the space `Main`. On the other hand I know of no good notation for the parent-child relationship, so for the moment I will invent `parent > child` as notation, i.e.`Sandbox.WebHome` > `Sandbox.TestPage1` means that the page with name `WebHome` in the `Sandbox` space is the parent of `TestPage1` in the same space.

[image: different navigations]

You can see the parent-child relationship in the small breadcrumb on top of the content section of the page just above the title. The topmost navigation, however, shows the Wiki / Space / Page membership. i.e in which wiki and space the page is. What the sidebar shows depends on which navigation panels you have installed.

### Why it didn't work as expected

What you can change in the editor is only the parent-child relationship. So I assume you have a page `Sushi` in the `Food` space and the `WebHome` of that space as parent, i.e. `Food.WebHome > Food.Sushi`

After changing the parent to `Japan.WebHome` page, the parent-child relationship now looks like:  `Japan.WebHome > Food.Sushi`

As for the parent of `Food.Sushi` (in the breadcrumbs) you should see that it is the `Japan.WebHome` page. However the `Sushi` is still in the `Food` Space and is listed in the navigation under the pages in the `Food` space.

### How to make it work

To change the space membership of a page, go to that page and choose "Sushi" > "Rename" from the menu on the top (the menu that shows it "wrong" currently). On the upcoming page, type in the wanted space in the "new space" of the page (i.e. "Japan" in your case), leave the "new page" field alone and click "rename".

Afterwards the top navigation should show that your page is now in the "Japan" space, as it is renamed to `Japan.Sushi`